# Slider images don't resize

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, resize, slider

I have a responsive theme built in Bootstrap and the slider images aren't resizing. At about 900px the images disappear. This is also the same size the main menu moves below the logo.

Any ideas on how to cause the images to resize?
You can see the issue at: http://www.coloradobariatrics.com

Comment: Check the media queries if your CSS filers, one of them is hiding the elements. I'm not sure somebody will be brave enough to dig all your CSS filers ;)

Comment: I was looking at your code a bit, you really need to clean it up as there's too many CSS files and I doubt that you are using all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Insanely enough i found the error in your code. You are setting it to display none at 900px or less here **in line 2707 of your media.css file**

### CSS causing the issue

```
.pageSlider .ls-container
{
    display: none;
}
```

### CSS fixing the issue

You need to remove that or set it to `display: block;` like so:

```
.pageSlider .ls-container
{
    display: block;
}
```

The next issue is as your question title suggests, why are the images not resizing? The problem is that the slider you are using wasn't built with responsiveness in mind, and it's a parallax slider so it makes things just that much more complex.

Unfortunately my only suggestion here is to get a parallax responsive slider and [swap it with a plugin like this one](http://kreaturamedia.com/layerslider-responsive-jquery-slider-plugin/).

My other recommendation as mentioned in my comment above is that you clean your CSS and JS, it seems that you are using too many approaches to make the site responsive and all these assets are fighting over elements and styles.

It's pretty messy.

Comment: Thanks, I checked your link to plugin. It's the same one I'm currently using on the website.

Comment: Hehe, that's funny. Well my next guess here is that you have too much unused code and it's causing conflicts. There are currently too many combined approaches with different stylesheets and javascript that are all competing to make things responsive and some of those rules are messing things up. My recommendation is to clean, or if you don't feel like doing that, but up a bare bone fiddle together with bootstrap and the slider... this will be much easier to test and debug instead of having all those other stylesheets and js in the way.